# Spring-boot application not getting auto-deployed on startup

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I created a spring boot basic application in Eclipse IDE by following a tutorial online. When I am trying to run the application as a java application, the application is not getting deployed in embedded tomcat. I have googled a lot and tried some of the found solutions. However, none worked for me. I am pasting the code here. Please let me know any possible issues.
Code:-

pom.xml:-

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.test</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-example</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Spring Boot Example</name>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
</parent>



<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

SpringBootExample.java:-

```
package com.test;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import com.test.config.AppConfiguration;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Started main");
        SpringApplication.run(AppConfiguration.class, args);
        System.out.println("Ending main");
    }

}
```

AppConfiguration.java:-

```
package com.test.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import com.test.beans.SampleBean;

@Configuration
public class AppConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SampleBean getSampleBean() {
        return new SampleBean();
    }
}
```

SampleBean.java:-

```
package com.test.beans;

public class SampleBean {

    public SampleBean() {
        System.out.println("In constructor of SampleBean");
    }

}
```

Please note that bean of type SampleBean is getting created.But, application is closed after that. Below are the output logs:-

[image]

Comment: My code keeps popping out of code tag. Please suggest why and what should do to embed properly within code tag.

Comment: Try to write a controller. This application has no reason to live on...

Comment: Change `SpringApplication.run(AppConfiguration.class, args);` to `SpringApplication.run(SpringBootExample.class, args);` --- All examples I can find uses the class containing `main` and annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` in the `run()` parameter. Where did you see example using another class. Perhaps that is a site you should stop using, since it seems flawed.

Comment: @Andreas I tried using the same class and still the same result. Also, lots of sites suggested that I should pass the name of the class having spring beans configuration instead of self, so I tried it.

Comment: @Turo I created a controller,created a GET method and still got the same result.

Comment: I added the annotation @EnableAutoConfiguration to AppConfiguration class and it started working. The application was not able to determine which type of ServletWebServerFactory to create. After adding above annotation, it created it for embedded tomcat already present in tomcat.

Comment: Please *never* post code or errors as image. In turkey this service is unavailable btw. I am only here on holiday but if you use imgur you are cutting yourself of from a lot of people with good knowledge

Comment: @Marged I was having issues embedding the whole logs or even code in code tag. Can you please suggest how to post multiple lines of java code in a single code block?

Comment: Just paste the code and format it as such in the editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the annotation `@EnableAutoConfiguration` to `AppConfiguration.java` and it started working. The application was not able to determine which type of `ServletWebServerFactory` to create. After adding above annotation, it created it for embedded tomcat already present in classpath.